# Price Tier for Magento Custom Option Input - text field by its Length

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

In Magento 1.9,

I would like the product price to update ONLY when customer input more than 5 characters (or multiple the change-price for every 5 character added, if not too complex).

* The "price change Value" is set via the backend custom option, as below

[image: Price Change Value]

I want to add if-else to decide the onchange event, but fail to get current user input length.
file: ..\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\options\type\text.phtml

```
<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id=...>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you got any success to implement the such functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
<input type="text" onchange="if(this.value.length > 5) opConfig.reloadPrice()" id=...>
```

For every multiple of 5 above 5:

```
<input type="text" onchange="if(this.value.length && this.value.length % 5 == 0) opConfig.reloadPrice()" id=...>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is working BUT..even i change the input to less than 5 character the price do to the original price.<br>